# My Serverless deploy package is over 100 MB and the SLS command refuses to deploy it

Tags: aws-serverless

Although my app is fairly simple, it was deploying at 107Mb gzipped, and then I made some change that made it so large it wouldn’t deploy at all.  What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Reduce the size of your node_modules directory

Anything you don’t need — goes.   Delete your `node_modules/` directory and reinstall it to be sure it’s clean.

### 2. Really distinguish between dependencies and dev-dependencies

Anything you don’t need a run-time, mark as a dev-dependency, and put

```
package:
  excludeDevDependencies: true
```

in your `serverless.yml`.  Things you don’t need a run-time include compilers, type-libraries, and... Node.

### 3. Wait, Node?

Yeah, if you are like me, and prefer to develop in Node/Express and then deploy to Serverless, remember that Lambda runs its own version on Node, so your Node is a dev-dependency.  Ditto for things that only Node uses, like `ts-node` and `body-parser`.

### 4. Include rather than exclude

The `serverless.yml` should *include* the stuff you need, not exclude the stuff you don’t.  I write in Typescript (and you should too) and set my `tsconfig.json` to write everything to `build/`, so my entire package statement in `serverless.yml` is

```
package:
  excludeDevDependencies: true
  include:
    - build/**
```

Don’t add `node_modules/**` — the deployment process does that automatically and if you include it explicitly, you will defeat the `excludeDevDependencies` setting.

### 5. Check your work

You can practice by doing the following:

```
sls package
du -m -d 1 .serverless
```

The first statement quickly makes up the package, and then stops; the second lists the megabytes used by each artifact.  If there is a .zip file that looks too big, unzip it and then use `du` more to investigate what is taking up all the room.

By using these techniques, I got the 107Mb package down to 10Mb.